# AWS SAM deploy in GitLab CI/CD

Tags: gitlab-ci, aws-sam-cli

I'm looking to deploy a node lambda to AWS using `sam deploy` and am having issues with it in GitLab CI/CD.  First, I'm wondering if there is an image available that gives me access to both node and sam.  If not, is there a quicker way of installing the sam cli than the AWS documentation recommends?  I'd like to keep the runtime on my CI/CD reasonable, and they are recommending installing git, so that I can install linux Homebrew, so that I can install SAM.  I haven't been able to find anything relating to installing it with npm, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aws-sam-local) states, it is not currently supported for the newer version of `sam cli`. However, for the `0.2.11` version of sam, you could try out the following. Suppose that you're working on a `dev` branch, then

```
image: node:latest

stages: 
    - dev

development: 
    stage: dev 
    before_script: 
        - npm install -g aws-sam-local
    script: 
        ...
        ...
    environment: dev
    only: 
        - dev
```

Comment: I suspect this answer is correct, but I'm running into an issue: `Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/aws-sam-local/bin'`, and if I try to sudo I get `/bin/bash: line 109: sudo: command not found`